# Overflow ellipsis combined with three-part "selected image"

Tags: css, pseudo-element, ellipsis

I've succeded in getting two spans with `overflow: ellipsis` to work inside a table cell, whilst remaining responsive.

The issue at hand is that I need to mark one of the two spans as selected using a 3-part image.

In its simplest form, I have a table with the following structure:

```
<table class="my-table table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="truncate-container">
                <span class="truncate selected">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
                <span class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
            </td>         
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.my-table {
    width: 100%;
}

.truncate-container {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate-container .truncate {
    width: 48%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;  
}

.selected {
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaQcG.png");
  display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
}

.selected::before,
.selected::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 28px;
}

.selected::before {
  left: -14px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2HC.png") no-repeat;
}

.selected::after {
  right: -8px;
  background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WA5B.png") 100% no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4ceuaws/

If you resize the HTML-pane, you can see the ellipsis working, but the selection isn't working as desired.

Can this particular combination of the pseudo-elements ::before and ::after together with ellipsis be done in pure CSS, or do I have to resort to JS (Angular filter) for the truncation?

Comment: It is clearly not liking the combination of `overflow:hidden` property applied to the `.truncate-container .truncate` selector and the use of pseudo-elements. My guess is that, since `:before` and `:after` are not elements in their own, the element is taking the entire allotted width, so the pseudo-elements are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options:

### Option 1:

Using pure HTML and CSS, you could generate your ellipsis resorting to three different spans: `tip`, `content` and `butt`.

### Option 2:

Use a little bit a jQuery magic to fill a `.selected` span, containing only the text to display, with the necessary span elements to generate the ellipsis on dom ready.

```js
$(".truncate.selected").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children("span").length > 0) return true;
    else $(this)
        .html('<span class="content">' + $(this).text() + '</span>')
        .prepend('<span class="tip" />')
        .append('<span class="butt" />');
});
```

```css
p {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.my-table {
    width: 100%;
}
.truncate-container {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.truncate-container .truncate {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.selected span {
    display:block;
    float:left!important;
}
.selected .content {
    height: 28px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaQcG.png");
    color: blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.selected .tip, .selected .butt {
    height: 28px;
}
.selected .tip {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2HC.png") no-repeat;
    width:14px;
}
.selected .butt {
    background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WA5B.png") 100% no-repeat;
    width:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Ellipsis generated manually from HTML</p>
<table class="my-table table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="truncate-container"> <span class="truncate selected">
                    <span class="tip"></span>
 <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
 <span class="butt"></span>
</span> <span class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Ellipsis generated dynamically using jQuery</p>
<table class="my-table table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="truncate-container"> <span class="truncate selected">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
 <span class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason, when running the snippet the ellipsis appears broken, but it does not on the edit screen nor on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/8fd5x39L/, so it's probably a Stack Overflow bug